# Refactor PHP script to do mysql update between 2 database servers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to finish a script that connects to two databases, each on a different server, and preforms an update. Basically, the tables being selected from and inserted to are identical: I did a dump/import the other day. The script needs to keep my local table up to date from the remote once since there will be daily records inserted into the remote one and I need to keep it up to date locally.

The key here is that I'm determining the new rows on the remote server by looking at the Auto-incremented Primary key that the tables share, `SESSIONID` . I'm trying to get my loop below to say, if the id exists in remote server and not local, then insert those records in local server.

I run the below script in powershell by typing php 'filename', and I get both of my successful connection messages, but then it hangs. After about 10 minutes, it had a memory error so I added `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`. After this it would still hang for about 10 minutes, and then say that MySQL server has gone away and result header couldn't be found, both errors occurring on the line where I check to see if the `$rowCount` failed.

Note: Replication and large dump/import/table recreations are not an option for us in this situation. We have several similar scripts to this running and we want to keep the same process here. I'm merely looking to resolve these errors or have someone give me a more efficient way of coding this script, perhaps using a max id or something along those lines.

Here's the script:

```
      ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
      $conn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);

      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }
      echo "Connected successfully";

      // Check connection2
      if ($conn2->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
      }
      echo "Connected successfully";


    //Start queries
    //Select All rows from the source phone database 
      $source_data = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from cdrdb.session");

      // Loop on the results
      while($source_item = $source_data->fetch_assoc()) {

          // Check if row exists in destination phone database
          $row_exists = $conn2->query("SELECT SESSIONID FROM ambition.session WHERE SESSIONID = '".$source_item['SESSIONID']."' ");

              //if query returns false, rows don't exist with that new ID.
              if (!$row_exists){

                    //Insert new rows into ambition.session
                    $conn2->query("INSERT INTO ambition.session (SESSIONID,SESSIONTYPE,CALLINGPARTYNO,FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,DIALPLANNAME,TERMINATIONREASONCODE,ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING,CREATIONTIMESTAMP,ALERTINGTIMESTAMP,CONNECTTIMESTAMP,DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP,HOLDTIMESECS,LEGTYPE1,LEGTYPE2,INTERNALPARTYTYPE1,INTERNALPARTYTYPE2,SERVICETYPEID1,SERVICETYPEID2,EXTENSIONID1,EXTENSIONID2,LOCATION1,LOCATION2,TRUNKGROUPNAME1,TRUNKGROUPNAME2,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM,SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO,ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1,SERVICEEXTENSION1,SERVICEEXTENSION2,SERVICENAME1,SERVICENAME2,MISSEDUSERID2,ISEMERGENCYCALL,NOTABLECALLID,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID,ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO,ACCOUNTCODE,ACCOUNTCLIENT,ORIGINATINGLEGID,SYSTEMRESTARTNO,PATTERN,HOLDCOUNT,AUXSESSIONTYPE,DEVICEID1,DEVICEID2,ISLEG1ORIGINATING,ISLEG2ORIGINATING,GLOBALCALLID,CADTEMPLATEID,CADTEMPLATEID2,ts,INITIATOR,ACCOUNTNAME,APPNAME,CALLID,CHRTYPE,CALLERNAME,serviceid1,serviceid2)
                    VALUES ('".$source['SESSIONID']."' ,
                            '".$source['SESSIONTYPE']."' ,
                            '".$source['CALLINGPARTYNO']."' ,
                            '".$source['FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO']."',
                            '".$source['DIALPLANNAME']."',
                            '".$source['TERMINATIONREASONCODE']."',
                            '".$source['ISCLEARINGLEGORIGINATING']."',
                            '".$source['CREATIONTIMESTAMP']."',
                            '".$source['ALERTINGTIMESTAMP']."',
                            '".$source['CONNECTTIMESTAMP']."',
                            '".$source['DISCONNECTTIMESTAMP']."',
                            '".$source['HOLDTIMESECS']."',
                            '".$source['LEGTYPE1']."',
                            '".$source['LEGTYPE2']."',
                            '".$source['INTERNALPARTYTYPE1']."',
                            '".$source['INTERNALPARTYTYPE2']."',
                            '".$source['SERVICETYPEID1']."',
                            '".$source['SERVICETYPEID2']."',
                            '".$source['EXTENSIONID1']."',
                            '".$source['EXTENSIONID2']."',
                            '".$source['LOCATION1']."',
                            '".$source['LOCATION2']."',
                            '".$source['TRUNKGROUPNAME1']."',
                            '".$source['TRUNKGROUPNAME2']."',
                            '".$source['SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDFROM']."',
                            '".$source['SESSIONIDTRANSFEREDTO']."',
                            '".$source['ISTRANSFERINITIATEDBYLEG1']."',
                            '".$source['SERVICEEXTENSION1']."',
                            '".$source['SERVICEEXTENSION2']."',
                            '".$source['SERVICENAME1']."',
                            '".$source['SERVICENAME2']."',
                            '".$source['MISSEDUSERID2']."',
                            '".$source['ISEMERGENCYCALL']."',
                            '".$source['NOTABLECALLID']."',
                            '".$source['RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID']."',
                            '".$source['ORIGINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO']."',
                            '".$source['ACCOUNTCODE']."',
                            '".$source['ACCOUNTCLIENT']."',
                            '".$source['ORIGINATINGLEGID']."',
                            '".$source['SYSTEMRESTARTNO']."',
                            '".$source['PATTERN']."',
                            '".$source['HOLDCOUNT']."',
                            '".$source['AUXSESSIONTYPE']."',
                            '".$source['DEVICEID1']."',
                            '".$source['DEVICEID2']."',
                            '".$source['ISLEG1ORIGINATING']."',
                            '".$source['ISLEG2ORIGINATING']."',
                            '".$source['GLOBALCALLID']."',
                            '".$source['CADTEMPLATEID']."',
                            '".$source['CADTEMPLATEID2']."',
                            '".$source['ts']."',
                            '".$source['INITIATOR']."',
                            '".$source['ACCOUNTNAME']."',
                            '".$source['APPNAME']."',
                            '".$source['CALLID']."',
                            '".$source['CHRTYPE']."',
                            '".$source['CALLERNAME']."',
                            '".$source['serviceid1']."',
                            '".$source['serviceid2']."')");
                  }
      }
```

Comment: have you try a where clause like "where SESSIONID>".$Last_update_Record_sessionID"? and then, use a single shot query of updates (multiple values single query)

Comment: I haven't. I started down the current route and went with it. Unfortunately, I'm new to the PHP meets MySQL area. I normally just do this within a SQL editor

Comment: How exactly would I structure that

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This is in urgent need of some kind of array to define the columns you're using rather than hand-typing all out. You could have typos in there and never know.

Comment: @tadman that was my original attempt, but I was then given this as a supposed better option. I'd rather do something like an insert ignore, or just store the selected variables in an array and insert them if their ID is newer then what's in the destination table

Comment: Keep in mind that PDO allows binding of named placeholders which makes queries like this very easy to write and execute. `INSERT INTO x (y) VALUES (:y)` and then `execute(array('y' => 'y_value'))` is pretty tidy.

Comment: I just have a lot to learn on that, I'm coming from the SQL side of things and am newer to how it works within php

Comment: I'm at least getting to a better point with it, but now I'm getting ```incorrect datetime value for column 'ALERTINGTIMESTAMP'. It seems to be where a null value is, but the column accepts null values

Answer (score 3):

```
// Check if row exists in destination phone database
$row_exists = $conn2->query("SELECT SESSIONID FROM ambition.session WHERE SESSIONID = '".$source_item['SESSIONID']."' ");

//if query returns false, rows don't exist with that new ID.
if (!$row_exists){
```

This is incorrect: if query returns false, the query failed to execute. You need to check `if ($row_exists->num_rows == 0)` instead. The way your code is now, it will always insert every record, again and again. Since you're not checking for errors on the `INSERT` query you're not noticing the failures you're getting on the duplicate entries for your `SESSIONID` column (I assume that's the primary key column in your local database as well).

Additionally, it would probably be a lot faster if you only SELECT the sessions you don't already have. Since you're working with an auto increment column, you can pretty much assume that anything in the remote database with a SESSIONID that came after the latest SESSIONID from your local database is new:

```
//Start queries
$latest_result = $conn2->query("SELECT MAX(`SESSIONID`) FROM `ambition`.`session`");
$latest_row = $latest->fetch_row();
$latest_session_id = $latest_row[0];

//Select All rows from the source phone database 
$source_data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `cdrdb`.`session` WHERE `SESSIONID` > $latest_session_id");
```

Tables in MySQL are usually sorted by the primary key column by default, but if you're concerned about the order in which you're inserting data in your local database in case your script gets interrupted for some reason, you could add an explicit `` ORDER BY `SESSIONID` ASC `` to the query.

Comment: Ok I ran this, updating the code in my question now, but I still get one more error (after fixing a variable name). I get ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 60PS```. How do I know what line 60PS is?

Comment: Don't know where the "PS" comes from, it's probably line 60. Since you're not escaping any of your values, you're probably trying to insert a session that has an `'` in one of its columns. Try using a prepared statement instead of just dropping the variables into the query.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to do that. Again, I'm just coming from more of the SQL side, not so much PHP. However, could I implement something to escape the values instead?  Line 60 is just the Insert part of my query up to the end of the column names just before the ```VALUES``` Line

Comment: You **could** use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string), but you **should** use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) with [bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead.

Comment: By the way, please don't change the code in your question based on the answers you get, by doing that a lot of context is lost if anyone else finds this page as the answer to a similar issue. If you change your code and still have questions about it, add the updated code below the original code.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I didn't really think about that side of it. I'll keep in mind for the future though! I'm trying to implement that update now